# Drupal Page Manager: load secondary content depending on primary content field criteria

Tags: drupal, panels

Scenario:
I have two content types: Attorneys (Name, Image, Bio fields) and Decisions (Decision, Date, Summary, Assigned Attorneys fields)

I am trying achieve a setup with Page Manager and Panels wherein, when an attorney's bio page is visited, a panel underneath the main attorney content loads all Decisions who's Assigned Attorneys field matches the attorney on the current page. There will ever only be one attorney on a given page, but any given number of decision nodes underneath.

I've poked and prodded around Page Manager after viewing several tutorials and can't seem to get it to work! Any ideas? Thx!

**UPDATE**

OK, here's a clearer picture. Take the following two Attorneys:

!http://reubenlara.com/blog/adam.png

!http://reubenlara.com/blog/carlos.png

Below them is a views block that references all existing Decisions. So far, I've only entered two. Both decisions are showing up on both attorneys as a default view. However, Decisions should only show up if the attorney is listed in the Decision's Attorney(s) field, like so:

!http://reubenlara.com/blog/recordedDecision.png

Decisions can have multiple attorneys associated with them. I have this set up as a multi-select list item in the form that creates a new Decision content entry. In this case, the Decision only lists Adam. This Decision should not show up on Carlos' bio page.

How do I set views up so that the Decision block knows what attorney page it's currently on and only lists those with a common attorney?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using views. Create two views, one fetches information about the Attorneys by recognizing the arguments in the URL and the second one fetches other details as desired. Now, add them both to panels. Panels and page managers doesn't manipulates such data as views does! They are for displaying the data only.

Comment: ahhh, no wonder. So, in views (which i tried and tried to wrangle as well), how do I set up a contextual filter for "Decisions>Attorney Assigned" field that queries the page title of the page it's currently being viewed on (which would be the name of the assigned attorney, in this case)?

Comment: Both content types are related by Decisions nodes, right? You need to create two display with same contextual filter but different relationship. in first view, you may not require any relationship but for the other display, you should use 'all the decision nodes associated with this Attorney'. Where 'this attorney' comes from URL and that is you contextual filter.

Comment: Please se UPDATE above. Thanks so much for your help, I feel like i've tried every combination of settings I know!